# How to iterate through a QStandardItemModel completely?

Tags: c++, qt5, qstandarditemmodel, qmodelindex, qstandarditem

I have a QStandardItemModel, which I display in q QTreeView. Works fine.

To highlight relevant rows I want to highlight some of them: Therefore I have a QStringList with the names of the QStandItem* s to be highlighted.

```
QStringList namesToBeHighlighted = getNames();

QModelIndex in = myModel->index(0, 0);

if ( in.isValid() ) {

    for (int curIndex = 0; curIndex < myModel->rowCount(in); ++curIndex) {

        QModelIndex si = myModel->index(curIndex, 0, in);
        QStandardItem *curItem = myModel->itemFromIndex(si);

        if (curItem) {
           QString curItemName = curItem->text();

           if ( namesToBeHighlighted.contains(curItem->text()) ) {
               curItem->setFont(highlightFont);
           }
           else curItem->setFont(unHighlightFont);
        }
    }
}
```

My Model has following structure:

Level_1
 +--> Level_11
 +--> Level_12
 +--> Level_13
Level_2
 +--> Level_21
 +--> Level_22
 +--> Level_23
...

Here, it iterates trough Levels 11, 12 and 13 then it stops.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I hope it helps you:

```
void forEach(QAbstractItemModel* model, QModelIndex parent = QModelIndex()) {
    for(int r = 0; r < model->rowCount(parent); ++r) {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(r, 0, parent);
        QVariant name = model->data(index);
        qDebug() << name;
        // here is your applicable code
        if( model->hasChildren(index) ) {
            forEach(model, index);
        }
    }
}

QStandardItemModel model;
    QStandardItem* parentItem = model.invisibleRootItem();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("item %0").arg(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            item->appendRow(new QStandardItem(QString("item %0%1").arg(i).arg(j)));
        }
        parentItem->appendRow(item);
        parentItem = item;
    }
forEach(&model);
```

Comment: Lines 7-9 are unnecessary, since forEach will return immediatly anyway if `model->rowCount() == 0`